# how to extract commit message from mercurial using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, mercurial

I am new to mercurial and I want to extract my last commit message from mercurial using powershell script and store it in word document.

Comment: Have you tried anything? `hg log` should be good enough. See docs at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/log

Answer (score 1):

If you can

- Rum OS-command from PowerShell
- intercept it's stdout

you can read `hg help log`+`hg help templating`+`hg help revsets`, build and use smth. like

```
hg log -r tip -T'{desc}'
```

for already commited changeset. For intercepting commit-message in pre*-hook code will be slightly more tricky

Answer (score 1):

This might be late.
We can just get the latest commit message from .gitignore file.